# Train a model for unstructured data

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I am new to Machine Learning. I want to develop Curriculum Vitae recommender system. I want to determine how similar 2 CVs are, and given a random CV, it suggest which cluster of CVs it belongs to?

This is what I've already done, following a [blog post](http://omkarpathak.in/2018/12/18/writing-your-own-resume-parser):

1. I have a folder containing lot of CVs or resume text documents in plain text format (.txt).
2. I have done pre-processing on this data, like tokenization, stop words removal, stemming.
3. I extracted the Candidate's name, email-id, contact number, education and experience.

I am confused with how to train the data and how do I create a model for that. More specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Now how to create a model on text data?
2. Which algorithm I should apply on this data?

Please anyone answer. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What pre-processing have you done? What does your final dataset look like?
What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have applied the preprocessing steps like tokenization, stop words removal, stemming. And I extracted the Candidate's name, email-id, contact number, education and  experience. Now how to create a model on text data that I do not have an idea. @Dan Carter

Comment: I'm not clear as to what your model is trying to achieve?. What is the end goal of your project?

Comment: I want to develop CV recommender system. @Itachi

Comment: Do you mean, you want to determine how similar 2 CVs are, and if you give a random CV, it suggest which cluster of CVs it belongs to?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @Itachi

Comment: From the information that you say you've already extracted, names, mails and phones are identifiers. There's no reason to expect that they would be indicative for any clustering/similarity. Could you please clarify in more details how you're representing the extracted education and experience?

Comment: I have done it by the help of this blog. https://www.omkarpathak.in/2018/12/18/writing-your-own-resume-parser/

Comment: If your skills and education are indicated by extracted words, your dataset is equivalent to [tagged users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943391/how-to-cluster-users-based-on-tags). If you are still interested in a wider range of possible approaches, consider [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/best-approach-for-this-unsupervised-clustering-problem-with-categorical-data/) and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/clusering-based-on-categorical-variables) questions and the corresponding answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on a similar project with JDs, we basically created a word2vec model for words in JD, the result were good as we had lots of JDs. 
Basically, what word2vec does is convert a word to vectorial representation which signifies context. 
You can check the documentation here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/

You may extract skills or other stuff from CVs, and do a semantic similarity based on w2v model. You may use a custom formulae for comparing similarity. Other things could be education, experience, similar projects etc

Comment: I will try this and If I'll have any question then I'll ask you. @Itachi

Comment: I have done till w2v. After that what to do? How do I recommend resume? @Itachi